# What disease does Saccharopolyspora erythraea cause?

Tags: microbiology, homework, bacteriology, pathology, infectious-diseases

For an examination assignment I have to find a disease caused by the bacterial species *Saccharopolyspora erythraea*, but I have searched the internet and have found no report of patients being infected with *Saccharopolyspora erythraea*. The only information I found on this bacteria is about its production of erythromycin.

Comment: I wonder whether the person setting the exam has made a mistake. For example in the paper describing the sequencing of the genome of this bacterium (Latin singular — bacteria is plural) all that is mentioned is its importance as a source of the antibiotic erythromycin.

Comment: The only mention I find for isolation of a related species in the same gents from a patient is this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/19406809/ and it is not the cause of the disease there.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant I genus (T9 typing).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE!  I suggest listing the databases you have consulted — an expert might be able to help you based on knowing where you've looked either by confirming that you've searched exhaustively and that there is likely nothing to be found, or by directing to a source you might have missed.

Comment: @LazorLord. One possible source of confusion here is the change in naming and classification of micropolyspora within the family Nocardiacae, among whose species are the various nocardia responsible for 'nocardiosis'; which of itself is worthy of study.  Evidently certain members of this family are capable of arriving on Earth on meteorites.